# Creating DirectX Device using Device.Device(Int32,DeviceType,Control,CreateFlags,PresentParameters[]) Constructor (Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D)

Tags: .net, wpf, directx

I am new to DirectX programming, I have this doubt about DirectX Device constructor. As per Microsoft's Documentation we can create a device using

Device.Device(Int32,DeviceType,Control,CreateFlags,PresentParameters[]) Constructor (Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D).

What exactly 1st parameter means here? MS docs says

"adapter System.Int32
Ordinal number that identifies which physical device the object represents. Device 0 is the default device. The highest value that can be used in this parameter is one less than the total number of physical devices."

What do we mean by physical device here. Are we referring to monitors connected to system? Or is it anything else?

Also, I want my application to use a particular graphic card, if there are more than one graphic cards. Is there any way to enumerate through graphic card list? Can we force our application to use a particular graphic card? If yes, how can I do that? I have tried using AdapterInformation class but I believe  that corresponds to monitors connected not graphic cards.

Any help would be of great value.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is the number of the display adapter. In most cases an adapter is equivalent to a physical monitor that is connected to the computer.

You can get all display adapters by iterating over `Manager.Adapters`. The `Information` property contains graphics card specific information. Just try it and see, which pieces of information are useful for you to identify the graphics card. If you have identified the adapters of the target card, you can choose one of them.

Comment: Nico, I need to be able to use a particular graphic card if more than one cards are available. Is it possible with DirectX? I tried Manager.Adapters but that corresponds to monitors not graphic cards. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can use e.g. the `.Information.Description`, which will return the graphics card's name or the `.Information.DeviceId`, which will return the graphics card's id. This is equal for all displays that are connected to the same graphics card.

Comment: Nico, The problem I am facing is that this API gives me information about monitors connected to system, and by using "Information" property I can fetch information about graphic card specific to that monitor, If other graphic card that is present on system but not being used at that time. I am not able to get information about that. May be I am not very clear, but what I am trying to do is to enumerate directly on graphic cards, then I will be able to use graphic card of my choice.

Comment: What I am getting by this API is just information about my primary card. I never get two card's info by this API even if I have two graphic cards installed on my system.